# ComponentDidMount() in Server-side render

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying to server-side render my webpage for better performance but am running into an issue where my page's components `componentDidMount()`s aren't getting called.

For example, this is my main template file:

```
import React from 'react';
import Cube from './components/Cube/Cube.jsx';

class Index extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
          <html>
            <head>
              <title>{this.props.title}</title>
            </head>
            <body>
              <Cube />
            </body>
          </html>
    );
  }
}
```

And my Cube.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';

class Cube extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("Hey!");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Cube;
```

I'm not seeing "Hey!" getting logged out in my pm2 logs nor in my chrome console even though I'm seeing the `<h1>Hello</h1>` when the page loads. This is stopping me from having any sort of logic for my component.

How do I get around this problem and make my subcomponents's `componentDidMount()` get called? Note I'm using [`express-react-views`](https://github.com/reactjs/express-react-views) for my server-side rendering.

Comment: I am not sure if you can use `componentDidMount()` while doing server side rendering. I remember seeing the use of polyfills for node to overlook it (?).

Comment: I think server side rendering only generate static html markup. It does not include your react code. So you cannot see your log. You need to include the bundle along with that markup that will take care of that logic.

Comment: @Prakashsharma do you mean the `bundle.js` from webpack?

Comment: @MarksCode yes.

Comment: @Prakashsharma can you please help me. I'm getting bundle.js on my webpage but no `componentDidMount()` are getting called...

Answer (score 5):

I think the only lifecycle hook that will be called server side is `componentWillMount` as explained [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount)

Even then you would not see output on Chrome's console. You are only likely to see it in your node logs.

Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: So you are better off using `componentWillMount` or `constructor` to get data for JSX elements. If that is what you are intending to do. Also, I found this useful: http://www.crmarsh.com/react-ssr/

Answer (score 0):

Problem is as I my self found out few days ago using `Next.js` that React application is not mounted. What that means is that Server Side Rendering is exactly that. React app is 'rendered' aka static HTML file is created on the server, and served to the browser. But in that process React is not mounted and no hooks are fired. Maybe `componentWillMount` I am not sure and have not tested.